# Run MySQL Query on chnage of HTML input=text filed onchange

Tags: php, html, ajax, onchange

What I am trying to do is when I type in in input text box to see if the value of the text box is in a DB row when text is entered in the box.

```
<input type='text' name='barcode'>
```

have it search the db onchange of the input field to look for the value of the barcode entered and echo the results of the row on the same page as the input field.

It looks like I have to use AJAX, but I am not familiar with that at all.

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest you use JQuery to do this. in your HTML File... you have this on your input, just ensure you include the jquery files appropriately. and anywhere in your page you have the input component with the onchange event. the output div is where the contents is displayed on the HTML page after hitting the database..

```
<input type='text' name='barcode' onchange="updateDB(this);"> 
<div id="outputdiv" class="outputdiv"></div>
```

in your javascript, you have a function similar to this,

```
function updateDB(object{
    //retrieve the value of the input... 
    //from object which represents the input
    var options = {
       type:'post',
       url: '/update/db.php',   //the script to update the database
       data: {"value":$(object).val()},
    };

    $.ajax(options)
    .done(function(data){  //if the request succeeds this part runs.
       $('#outputdiv').html(data);  
     })
     .fail(function(xhr, status, error){  
       //if the request fails this runs..
       //enter what to do if error occurs... 
     });

   }
```

Ensure to load the jquery file before calling the script. if you have your scripts in a different file. something similar to this, in your html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.13.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //your javascript goes here... 
</script>
```

then in your server file lets assume its php.... you input the code to query the database.. and relative to the url from your jquery-ajax script.

```
<?php 
    //connect to the database.. 
    //query the database and enter the   

    //read variable with 
    $variable = $_REQUEST['value'];

    //what ever you echo is received on the success(data)
    //and sent to the div tag on your html file.
 ?>
```

i hope this helps..

Comment: It has helped, I feel I am almost there. once the php code finds the data, how do I get it to display in the div tag?

Comment: this is where you display it in the div -   $('#outputdiv').html(data);  this line.. using the ID of the div, in the ajax function. look carefully.

Comment: I see, the something in my code must not be working, I do not see any results, when I enter in values in the search box. I just can not seem to know what is wrong

Comment: do you have teamviewer, installed on your system

Comment: I do, but not not comfortable with letting others connect. Sorry.  Could I send you the code somehow, if you would not mind taking a look?

Comment: ok.. just thought i could quickly help you resolve, your issue as i am about to step out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203131/discussion-between-vlad-and-ande-caleb).